# How can I get a text of one column of the table using testcafe and then i assert its eql to "something"

Tags: javascript, java, testing, automation, testcafe

I have a page with "search field" and "search button" and a table with 5 columns. I want to make an automation test with testcafe + javascript as following:

1: Type in "search field" - DONE

2: Click "search button" - DONE

3: Get the TEXT of all elements in the second column and assert it that its equal to "something"

I made it with Java + Selenium WebDriver. It was done with  but I'm not that good with JavaScript and still cant investigate how to do it.

Comment: Do you have an example of a website that has these same DOM elements?  You could try and walk the DOM to locate the property for each cell....but without knowing what the IDs and Class names look like, it is difficult to give an answer.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_filters.asp

For example this table. When i search for "Do" then i want to assert all rows in the table that contain "Do" in the "Lastname" column

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like the following code help you:

```
const secondColumnElements = Selector('table tr td:nth-child(2n)');
const elementsCount = await secondColumnElements.count;
let text = '';

for (let i = 0; i < elementsCount; i++)
    text += await secondColumnElements.nth(i).textContent;

await t.expect(text).eql('something');
```

Comment: Below i post the answer, can you help :)

Answer (score 1):

When i run the test the following error is shown:

```
errMsg: 'AssertionError: expected ' +
       "'Do[object Object]' to deeply " +
       "equal 'Do'"
```

Here is the code:

```
const secondColumnElements = Selector (Selector)
const elementsCount = await secondColumnElements.count;

let text = '';

for (let i = 0; i < elementsCount; i += 1) {
 text += secondColumnElements.nth(i).textContent;
}

await testController.expect(text).eql('Do');
});
```

Comment: Take note that you need to await the textContent property result. You accidentally lost the `await` keyword in the loop.

Comment: Still the same problem.
    Do[object Object]' to deeply " +
       "equal 'Do'"

Comment: It's strange, adding the `await` keyword before the `secondColumnElements.nth()....` should solve the issue. Could you please provide us with a detailed example demonstrating the issue?